# How to open a url as a bootstrap modal window?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have this line of PHP:

---

```
$STRING .= $b_f.'<a href="'.get_home_url().'/wp-login.php" class="ua5 '.$linkclass.'">'.$CORE->_e(array('head','5','flag_link')).'</a>'.$b_a;
```

---

This url opens now as a new webpage. How can i open it as a dialog/modal window instead? In my code i have bootstrap installed.

Comment: Try this solution http://jsfiddle.net/XUnj8/1/ it helped me.

Comment: Vic Abreu, it won't open a modal, by clicking the button it just make the webpage right scroller to dissapear. any suggestions?

Comment: Not really Yaniv Noodelman, this is a working example that worked for me and it's already working on JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks Vic Abreu, will try again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this "trick":

```
<a href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/" class="btn bootpopup" title="This is title" target="popupModal2">Open modal</a>

<div id="popupModal2" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <iframe src="" style="zoom:0.60" frameborder="0" height="250" width="99.6%"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the js:

```
$('.bootpopup').click(function(){
  var frametarget = $(this).attr('href');
  var targetmodal = $(this).attr('target');
  if (targetmodal == undefined) {
    targetmodal = '#popupModal';
  } else { 
    targetmodal = '#'+targetmodal;
  }
  if ($(this).attr('title') != undefined) {
    $(targetmodal+ ' .modal-header h3').html($(this).attr('title'));
    $(targetmodal+' .modal-header').show();
  } else {
     $(targetmodal+' .modal-header h3').html('');
    $(targetmodal+' .modal-header').hide();
  }  
    $(targetmodal).on('show', function () {
        $('iframe').attr("src", frametarget );   
    });
    $(targetmodal).modal({show:true});
  return false;

});
```

Just pass your link to the button's `href`.

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/bqBoKhqoQt)

Comment: @YanivNoodelman This is a woking example. Check my answer edit - there is a demo link.

Comment: Thanks Slim, I will do so